# Automate super user login in a shell script with password hardcoding

Tags: sudo, su

I need to log in to console as a super user through a shell script without typing password. Password should be hard coded to the script.
ex- sudo su psadmin(psadmin is my username).

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Review your control flow, what you want to do is not a good idea.

That said, there is an easy way to achieve what you want without hardcoding a PW: SSH to yourself

1. Configure SSH to allow root login from localhost
2. if not already done, run `ssh-keygen`
3. run `ssh-copy-id root@localhost`, you can now ssh to root without a pw
4. start your script via `sshroot@localhost /path/to/script`

Again: I advise strongly not to do that, it might be much easier to adapt your `sudoers` file to allow `sudo /path/to/script` without a PW

Comment: As per the requirement i can't do it coz i don't have permission. I need to run this(shell script) on 12 servers.

Comment: Actually i'm connecting to server using ssh.First i connects to a bridge and then connect to the  server. After that i need to login there as a sudo su psadmin. That's the requirement i'm having current now.

Comment: So **once** per server you login manually run `sudo -s`and configure the sudoers file to NOT ask for a PW for `su`. From then on you can just `ssh someuser@somehost sudo su` without a PW